# Проверка полей на заполнение

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста самую простую проверку полей на заполнение, что бы при нажатие на кнопку "Регистрация" без обновления страницы! рядом с полем которое не заполнено выводило "Заполните пожалуйста поле" и т.д другие поля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пожалуйста простой пример
[Проверка формы "на лету"](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=246)

Answer (score 4):

html

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="обработчик">      
        <div>
            <label>Имя</label>      
            <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
        </div>      
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

**используйте jQuery Form Plugin**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/form.js"></script>
```

последний js с названием form.js

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
                $('#form').validate(
                {   
                    // правила для проверки
                    rules:{
                        firstname: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 2,
                            maxlength: 30
                            }   
                    },

                    // выводимые сообщения при нарушении соответствующих правил
                    messages:{
                        "firstname":{
                            required: "Заполните это поле",
                            minlength: "От 2 до 30 символов",
                            maxlength: "От 2 до 30 символов"
                        }                       
                    },

                    // указаваем обработчик
                    submitHandler: function(form){
                        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                            target: '#preview', 
                            success: function() { 
                                $('#contact_form').slideUp("fast", function(){
                                $(this).before($("<div id='checkmark'><img src='img/check.png'><p>Ваша заявка принята!</p></div>").delay(6000));                                
                                 }
                                 ).delay(6000).slideDown('fast',function() {$(this).prev().remove();});
                                 $("#form").clearForm();
                                }                               
                            }) 
                            } 
                        }); 
                    });
</script>
```

css

```
form div{
    position: relative;
}
form label.error{
    position: absolute; top: 32px; left: 310px; 
    font: 14px/20px Tahoma; 
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;    
    background: #f00;
    width: 140px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #af0000;  
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Есть замечательные html5 атнибуты, как required, pattern